# How to get the output from the stored procedure when calling the procedure in python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I have written a stored procedure to delete the records from the table.and i am calling the procedure in the python using cursor. Eventhough i have used dbms_output.put_line i am not getting the output.

```
connection = dbconnect()
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.callproc('DELETE_ds',[id])
    print (c.fetchall())
    c.close()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

### storedprocedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_DATASET(DATASET_ID NUMBER,DATASET_ID OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM DATA_SET where DATA_SET_ID = DATASET_ID;
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

and i am using dbms output after delete statement in procedure but it is not writing any output.So if i want to get the id which has deleted or updated or inserted how do i get it from oracle.

Comment: It might depend on your driver, which driver you are using to connect to db, also which type of db are you using

Comment: did you issue `set serveroutput on` before calling the procedure.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes.

Comment: `dbms_output.put_line` works internally for the DBMS side, but seems you call the procedure from python's side( through a console or a subroutine ).